# How to get access to the default pandas dataframe plot palette?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, palette

How to get access to the default pandas dataframe colormap plot palette? In order to map their colors consistently to my columns? Digging into the sources from the [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) I can't find the default nor how to get the corresponding list of values ... the default uses these pastel style colors that are much nicer than Red or DarkRed etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas uses matplotlib default settings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.DataFrame(columns=plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']).T.assign(a=range(10),b=range(10)).T.plot()
```

[image]